# List Senders from a Shared Mailbox Folder (Recursively)

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to get a full list of senders to an specific shared mailbox i have access to (vía Outlook).

So far I am using this small but handy script to choose the selected folder as I have no idea on how to call as a parameter (Param) the folder I want to check:

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type] 
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$Inbox = $namespace.pickfolder()
$Inbox.items | Select-Object -Property SenderName
```

After that I filter the output depending on the info I need (in this case, senders).

This forces me to choose the folder MANUALLy, I just want to set it as a parameter to the script.

How should I pass the specific folder as a parameter?.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood that correctly, you yould create a function where you pass the Inbox Name

```
function GetSenders
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$Inbox
    )
    Begin
    {
        Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
        $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type] 
        $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
    }
    Process
    {
        "Your Script here - What should happen with the Inbox?"
    }
    End
    {
        Write-Host "Script has Finished"
    }
}
```

When you load this Function, you can just write `GetSenders -Inbox "InboxName"`